# how to enable http/2 on apache2 using ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: ubuntu, apache-2.4, virtualhost, http

I have VPS server running ubuntu 20.04 (apache2) and is using http/1.1 and I want to upgrade to http/2

The domain is already configured using v-hosts (and has the ssl installed - lets encrypt).

Testing the current protocol:

```
$ curl -I https://my-domain.com
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 12 Mar 2021 17:32:01 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu)
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

Steps that I done to upgrade to http/2:

```
1) sudo a2enmod http2

2) add in virtual host (ex: /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/my-domain.com-le-ssl.conf) the line:
Protocols h2 http/1.1     

3) check the config
sudo apache2ctl configtest

4) Restart the web server
sudo systemctl reload apache2
```

Test again the ptotocol:

```
$ curl -I https://my-domain.com
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 12 Mar 2021 17:57:07 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu)
Upgrade: h2
Connection: Upgrade
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

As you can see it still using the http/1.1

What did I miss ???

**UPDATE**

apache2 loaded modules

```
 $ sudo apachectl -M
 Loaded Modules:
 core_module (static)
 so_module (static)
 watchdog_module (static)
 http_module (static)
 log_config_module (static)
 logio_module (static)
 version_module (static)
 unixd_module (static)
 access_compat_module (shared)
 alias_module (shared)
 auth_basic_module (shared)
 authn_core_module (shared)
 authn_file_module (shared)
 authz_core_module (shared)
 authz_host_module (shared)
 authz_user_module (shared)
 autoindex_module (shared)
 deflate_module (shared)
 dir_module (shared)
 env_module (shared)
 expires_module (shared)
 filter_module (shared)
 headers_module (shared)
 http2_module (shared)
 mime_module (shared)
 mpm_prefork_module (shared)
 negotiation_module (shared)
 php7_module (shared)
 reqtimeout_module (shared)
 rewrite_module (shared)
 setenvif_module (shared)
 socache_shmcb_module (shared)
 ssl_module (shared)
 status_module (shared)
```

php 7.4.3 installed

```
php 
libapache2-mod-php 
php-mysql 
php-cli 
php-mbstring 
php-imagick 
php-xml 
php-gd 
php-zip 
php-curl 
php-opcache 
php-soap 
php-bcmath
```

vhost config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@my-domain.com
    ServerName my-domain.com
    ServerAlias www.my-domain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/my-domain.com/public

    Protocols h2 http/1.1 

    <Directory /var/www/my-domain.com/public/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =my-domain.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.my-domain.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

and the ssl config:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin admin@my-domain.com
    ServerName my-domain.com
    ServerAlias www.my-domain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/my-domain.com/public

    Protocols h2 http/1.1 

    <Directory /var/www/my-domain.com/public/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/my-domain.com/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/my-domain.com/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

**UPDATE 2**

What I found in the error.log (apache)

```
[http2:warn] [pid 507] AH10034: The mpm module (prefork.c) is not supported by mod_http2. The mpm determines how things are processed in your server. HTTP/2 has more demands in this regard and the currently selected mpm will just not do. This is an advisory warning. Your server will continue to work, but the HTTP/2 protocol will be inactive.
```

Probably this is the reason. Maybe using mpm_event instead of mpm_prefork will work.

I am not sure if I need the php-fpm...

Comment: Funny, it looks like curl is misbehaving, rather than your web server. What version of curl did you use? On what operating system?

Comment: @MichaelHampton curl 7.68 on ubuntu 20.04 ... and apache2 I have upgrade it to 2.4.46 .... but the same problem

Comment: Very strange, that version of curl should work correctly. Is something wrong with your Internet connection? Try `curl -I https://stackoverflow.com/` which gives an HTTP/2 response on my Ubuntu 20.04 test system.

Comment: testing for stackoverflow gives: HTTP/2 200

Comment: Bizarre. What is your actual domain name?

Comment: Hm, it definitely doesn't work. It looks like it should, but it doesn't. What is your Apache configuration?

Comment: @MichaelHampton sorry for the late reply. I updated the post. If something else is needed, please ask. The installation of apache and ssl certificate was simple - the same as in this tutorials. (apache install - https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-the-apache-web-server-on-ubuntu-20-04) and ssl install (https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-apache-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-20-04) ... nothing fancy :)

Comment: Oh, that bit is important. You shouldn't be using prefork anymore, this being the latest in a long line of reasons. Switch to the event MPM.

Comment: @MichaelHampton http/2 will work if using CLI ? Or must use fpm ?

Comment: CLI or fpm? What are you talking about?

Comment: @MichaelHampton in phpinfo() ... at the beginning: Server API => Command Line Interface. Should I use Server API => FPM/FastCGI  ? or to be more specific: libapache2-mod-fcgid or libapache2-mod-php ?

Comment: Right, you can't have embedded PHP with any other Apache MPM than prefork (which is one of the other major reasons to not use prefork; embedding web apps in the web server turned out to be a really bad idea). You'll also need to switch to php-fpm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Replacing the mpm_prefork with mpm_event
2. using php-fpm (libapache2-mod-fcgid) instead of (libapache2-mod-php)

solve the problems.

The credit goes to @MichaelHampton!